# C# - AAMVAID library to read driver's licenses

Tags: library, c#

I am looking for a library for my .NET c# web service and need to read the back of driver's licenses as they are scanned. What is the best library that meets the criteria below?

- It should work offline (I do not want to send my images to a 3rd party service)
- can by used in .NET FX or .NET Core or .NET 5
- supports different formats for loading

Answer (score 0):

the company I work for actually does image processing that can help with the driver license recognition. The back of the cards use a PDF417 barcode which the barcode engine can read and parse. They provide a free 60-day trial evaluation of the entire SDK if you wanted to check it out.
https://www.leadtools.com/downloads

The install has a demo application for barcode reading for .netcore. And one specifically for .NET driver license reading. And all of the demos come with the source code used to create them, which personally it always helps me to see when I'm developing my own apps with it.

the code implementation is pretty straight forward. This is some example code showing that from a blog post
https://www.leadtools.com/blog/document-imaging/barcode/reading-writing-aamva-barcodes-drivers-licenses/

```
using (AAMVAID id = BarcodeData.ParseAAMVAData(data.GetData(), false))
{
   Console.WriteLine("Issuer Identification Number: " + id.IssuerIdentificationNumber);
   Console.WriteLine("First Name: " + id.FirstName.Value);
   Console.WriteLine("Last Name: " + id.LastName.Value);
   Console.WriteLine("Over 21?: " + id.Over21);
   // etc.
}
```

This is a tutorial guide and downloadable project you can take a look at too on the site.
https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/tutorials/barcode/cross-platform/java/extract-drivers-license-aamva-barcode.html

If you do download the trial those projects can be found below.
.NETcoreBarcode demo
C:\LEADTOOLS21\Examples\DotNetCore\CommandLine\BarcodeDemo
.NET Driver License Reader demo
C:\LEADTOOLS21\Shortcuts\Forms Recognition & Processing.NET Framework Class Libraries\Forms (Structured & Unstructured)\Driver License Reader